# mysqldump импорт новых таблиц

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

Делаю дамп БД, где есть новая таблица все ок:

```
mysqldump -uUSER -pPASS --databases DBNAME > uszn_dump.sql
```

Заливаю этот дамп в БД, где нет той новой таблицы, которая есть в дампе:

```
mysqldump -uUSER -pPASS --databases DBNAME < uszn_dump.sql
```

Старые таблицы обновились, но новая таблица не добавилась, как быть?

Comment: *как быть?* смотреть лог загрузки и выяснять, почему не была создана таблица, какая возникла ошибка на её CREATE TABLE.

Comment: откуда вы взяли программу/скрипт под названием `mysqldump`? насколько я вижу, в эту программу разработчиками не заложена функциональность программы `mysql`, и никаким «обновлением/восстановлением» данных она просто не умеет заниматься. начиная с того, что просто не читает *stdin* (куда вы второй приведённой командой пытаетесь передавать содержимое файла).

Comment: Например в Ubuntu пакет mysqldump по умолчанию идет в составе сервера MySQL лет 5 так точно, т.к. лабу писал в 2012 году по БД.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для импорта базы я всегда использую такой формат:

```
mysql -uDBlogin -pDBpass DBname < backup.sql
```

Честно говоря никогда не слышал об использовании **mysqldump** при импортировании. Попробуйте использовать **mysql** с перенаправлением дампа в него.

Можно также открыть файл через интерактивный режим **mysql**, но для просто загрузки дампа это ни к чему.

Comment: Очень долго через просто mysql

Comment: Делайте быстрее. Дампите только структуру, а данные гоните через CSV, после чего наслаивайте индексы и связи.

Comment: Может плохо гуглю, но стало действительно интересно возможен ли импорт через **mysqldump**. Ни одного рабочего примера не нашел.

Comment: @AlexandrSysoev, возможно, какие-то спец-сборки этой программы могут и выполнять функции программы `mysql`. проверил в трёх разных сборках (от очень древней до вполне современной) — не умеет в них программа `mysqldump` выполнять функцию программы `mysql`, и вообще игнорирует поданное на *stdin*.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin ну вот и я думаю, что программа `mysqldump` разрабатывалась только для упрощения создания дампа. За всю жизнь мне в голову не приходила мысль использовать её иначе :)

Не исключаю, что у автора вопроса есть причины думать иначе.